# 2D Ising Model, heat capacity decreases with lattice size

Tags: python, c++, monte-carlo

## The problem

I'm trying to make a metropolis simulation of the 2D Ising model.

Basically, it's the following, for each monte-carlo step:

1. Visit each lattice site,
2. Compute energy required to flip the spin: `dE`
3. If $exp(-\frac{dE} {kT}) > p$ where `p` is a random number in [0,1], flip the spin, else leave it.

Heat capacity I retrieve from the Fluctuation dissipation theorem:

$ C_v = \frac{\sigma_E^2}{k_B T^2}$

My code reproduces some of the expected behaviour: i.e. there's a critical transition at vaguely the right temperature, but:

Energy has a smoothed-out transition. Magnetisation is a sharp step down from 1 to 0, while energy continues to rise, and doesn't show any change of gradient.

The heat capacity shows a peak, but instead of rising when I increase the lattice size, the peak gets smaller.

The heat capacity is noisy: the peak is often doubled, and fitting it to a Lorentzian is a nightmare. Worse yet, running the simulation multiple times gets me the same data (as evidenced by the small errorbar.

My project is a c++ program that simulates a single lattice, and a python script that analyses the output. As of now the script pipes the program stdout and assigns it to internal variables. It's inefficient, but that's for debugging purposes.

## The code

The full code can be found here: [enter link description here](https://github.com/appetrosyan/Ising-Model-simulation.git). The code is a c++ program that runs a simulation on a single lattice and a python script that analyses the data.

The code snippets of importance (i.e. that don't contain the irrelevant housekeeping), are

### simulation.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include "include/simulation.h"

using namespace std;

/*
Advances the simulation a given number of steps, and updates/prints the statistics
into the given file pointer.

Defaults to stdout.

The number of time_steps is explcitly unsigned, so that linters/IDEs remind
the end user of the file that extra care needs to be taken, as well as to allow
advancing the simulation a larger number of times.
*/
void simulation::advance(unsigned int time_steps, FILE *output) {
  unsigned int area = spin_lattice_.get_size() * spin_lattice_.get_size();
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < time_steps; i++) {
    /*
    To simulate an adiabatic Ising lattice, uncomment this
    */
    // double temperature_delta = total_energy_/area - mean_energy_;
    // if (abs(temperature_delta) < 1/area){
    //   cerr<<temperature_delta<<"! Reached equilibrium "<<endl;
    // }
    // temperature_ += temperature_delta;

    if (time_ % print_interval_ == 0) {
      total_magnetisation_ = spin_lattice_.total_magnetisation();
      mean_magnetisation_ = total_magnetisation_ / area;
      total_energy_ = compute_energy(spin_lattice_);
      mean_energy_ = total_energy_ / area;
      print_status(output);
    }
    advance();
  }
}

/*
Advances the simulation a single step.

DOES NOT KEEP TRACK OF STATISTICS. Hence private.
*/
void simulation::advance() {
  // #pragma omp parallel for collapse(2)
  for (unsigned int row = 0; row < spin_lattice_.get_size(); row++) {
    for (unsigned int col = 0; col < spin_lattice_.get_size(); col++) {
      double dE = compute_dE(row, col);
      double p = r_.random_uniform();
      // float rnd = rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.);
      if (dE <0 || exp(-dE / temperature_) > p) {
        spin_lattice_.flip(row, col);
      }
    }
  }
  time_++;
}



/*
Computes the total energy associated with spins in the spin_lattice_.

I originally used this function to test the code that tracked energy as the lattice
itself was modified, but that code turned out to be only marginally faster, and
not thread-safe. This is due to a race condition: when one thread uses a neighborhood
of a point, while another thread was computing the energy of one such point in
the neighborhood of (row, col).
*/
double simulation::compute_energy(lattice &other) {
  double energy_sum = 0;
  unsigned int max = other.get_size();
  #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+ : energy_sum)
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < max; j++) {
      energy_sum += other.compute_point_energy(i, j);
    }
  }
  return energy_sum/2;
}


void simulation::set_to_chequerboard(int step){
  if (time_ !=0){
    return;
  }else{
    for (unsigned int i=0; i< spin_lattice_.get_size(); ++i){
      for (unsigned int j=0; j<spin_lattice_.get_size(); ++j){
        if ((i/step)%2-(j/step)%2==0){
          spin_lattice_.flip(i, j);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

## investigator.py

```
#! /usr/local/bin/python3
from os import mkdir
from os.path import exists
from subprocess import run, PIPE
from numpy import loadtxt, linspace, log, sqrt, append, exp,  \
    array, shape, inf, std, mean, argmax
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class Simulation:
    def __init__(self, magnetic_field=0.0, exchange_energy=1.0,
                 lattice_size=64, temperature=1.0, duration=50,
                 grain_size=0):
        self.magnetic_field = magnetic_field
        self.exchange_energy = exchange_energy
        self.lattice_size = lattice_size
        self.temperature = temperature
        self.grain_size = grain_size
        self.duration = duration
        file_path = 'data/' + str(self) + '.csv'
        if use_disk:
            self.data = self.load_from_disk(file_path)
        else:
            self.data = self.run()

    def times(self):
        return self.data[:, 0]

    def mean_magnetizations(self):
        return self.data[:, 1]

    def mean_energies(self):
        return self.data[:, 2]

    def load_from_disk(self, file_path):
        if not exists(path=file_path):
            self.run(file_path)
        data = loadtxt(file_path)
        data_duration = data[-1, 0] + self.duration/200 + 10
        if self.duration > data_duration:
            print('duration mismatch, ' + str(self.duration) + '!=' + str(
                data_duration), end='. re-', flush=True)
            self.run(file_path)
            data = loadtxt(file_path)
        return data

    def run(self, file_path=None):
        if file_path is None:
            file_path = 'data/' + str(self) + '.csv'
        # print('running simulation... ', self.duration, end=' ', flush=True)
        command = ['./main', '-d', str(self.duration), '-t',
                   str(self.temperature), '-n', str(self.lattice_size),
                   '-j', str(self.exchange_energy), '-H',
                   str(self.magnetic_field), '-c', str(self.grain_size)]
        if self.duration > 500:
            command.append('-p')
            command.append(str(int(self.duration/200)))
        if use_disk:
            command.append('-f')
            command.append(file_path)
            # print('Done! ')
            run(command)
        else:
            r = run(command, stdout=PIPE)
            raw_data = loadtxt(r.stdout.decode().split(sep='\n'),
                               delimiter='\t')
            # print('Done! ')
            return raw_data

    def __str__(self):
        return '(H=' + str(self.magnetic_field) + ')(J=' + str(
            self.exchange_energy) + ')(T=' + str(
            self.temperature) + ')(N=' + str(
            self.lattice_size) + ')' + str(self.grain_size)

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------

def save_plot(title):
    plt.legend(loc='best')
    plt.suptitle(title)
    file_name = title.replace(' ', '_')
    if not exists('figures/'):
        mkdir('figures/')
    plt.savefig('figures/%s.png'%file_name)
    plt.show()


# -------------------------------------------------------------------------


def smart_duration(temperature, multiplier=1.):
    return int(((10**5)*base_duration*multiplier)/(
                (temperature - t_c)**2 + breadth))




def theoretical_capacity(x, a, b, c, d):
    return c + (b*x)/((x - a)**2 + d)


def investigate_heat_capacity(lattice_sizes=None, temps=None, **kwargs):
    if temps is None:
        temps = linspace(1.5, 3, 10)
    if lattice_sizes is None:
        lattice_sizes = [16,32, 34, 36]

    fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=len(lattice_sizes), sharex='col')
    crit_temps = []
    for l, ax in zip(lattice_sizes, axes):
        print('===',l)
        crit_temps.append(fit_and_plot_capacity(ax, l, temps, **kwargs))

    fig.set_size_inches(10.5, 10.5)
    plt.xlabel('temperature / arb. u.')
    save_plot('Heat capacity')
    return crit_temps


def fit_and_plot_capacity(ax, l, temps, **kwargs):
    """
    Plot the heat capacity of simulations at given temperature and lattice size.
    Afterwards fit a lorentzian and plot.

    Parameters:
    -----------
    ax : pyplot.axis
    what to plot to.

    l : int
    lattice size

    temps: numpy.array
    Array of temperatures where to evaluate heat capacity.

    Returns:
    -------
    popt[0]: float
    most likely critical temperature.
    """
    global use_disk
    use_disk = False
    simulations = [Simulation(lattice_size=l, temperature=t, duration=2)
                   for t in temps]
    # sigmas = [stdev(s.mean_energies[:]) for s in simulations]
    sigmas = array([multi_run(s, **kwargs) for s in simulations]).T[3]
    meta_sigmas = array([multi_run(s, **kwargs) for s in simulations]).T[4]
    # print(meta_sigmas)
    Cs = [sigma**2/(temp**2)*10**3 for temp, sigma in zip(temps, sigmas)]
    C_errs = Cs[:]*meta_sigmas[:]
    try:
        # popt, pcov = curve_fit(theoretical_capacity, temps*10, Cs,
                               # sigma=meta_sigmas, bounds=(
                # [min(temps) - .2, 0, 0, 0],
                # [max(temps) + .2, inf, inf, .7]))
        pass
    except RuntimeError:
        print('I\'m too dumb to fit')
        # popt = [temps[argmax(Cs)], (max(Cs) - min(Cs))/4, min(Cs),
                # (max(temps) - min(temps))/4]


    # ax.axvline(x=popt[0], ls='--', color='g')
    # ax.plot(temps, theoretical_capacity(temps, *popt), 'g-',
            # label='N = ' + str(l) + 'd = ' + str(popt[3]) + ' fit')
    ax.errorbar(temps, Cs, fmt='b.', yerr=C_errs, label='N = ' + str(l))
    ax.set_ylabel(r'C $\cdot 10^3$/ arb. u.')
    ax.axvline(x=t_c, ls='-.', color='k')
    ax.set_xticks(
        append(linspace(min(temps), t_c, 6), linspace(t_c, max(temps), 6)))
    ax.legend(loc='best')
    # return popt[0]


def multi_run(sim, re_runs:int=1, take_last:int=300):
    """
    Re run the Ising model simulation multiple times, and gather statistics.

    Parameters:
    ----------
    sim: simulation
    re_runs: int
    number of times to repeat simulation
    take_last: int
    How many of the final points to take statistics over.

    Returns:
    list:

    """
    global use_disk
    use_disk = False
    sim.duration = smart_duration(sim.temperature)
    print(sim.duration)
    magnetizations = []
    sigma_magnetizations = []
    energies = []
    sigma_energies = []
    for i in range(re_runs):
        sim.data = sim.run()
        # Make each run take 100% longer, so that we
        # can see if a system is still settling

        last_magnetizations = sim.mean_magnetizations()[-take_last:]
        magnetizations.append(abs(mean(last_magnetizations)))
        sigma_magnetizations.append(std(last_magnetizations))

        last_energies = sim.mean_energies()[-take_last:]
        energies.append(mean(last_energies))
        sigma_energies.append(std(last_energies))

    return [mean(magnetizations), mean(sigma_magnetizations),
            mean(energies), mean(sigma_energies),
            std(sigma_energies)/mean(sigma_energies)]


# -------------------------------------------------------------------------

def finite_size_scale(N, t_inf, a, v):
    return t_inf + a*(N**(-1/v))


def investigate_finite_size_scaling(critical_temperatures, lattice_sizes,
                                    **kwargs):
    if critical_temperatures is None:
        critical_temperatures = investigate_heat_capacity(lattice_sizes,
                                                          **kwargs)
    args, cov = curve_fit(finite_size_scale, lattice_sizes,
                                  critical_temperatures)
    plt.plot(lattice_sizes, critical_temperatures, 'b+', label='data')
    plt.plot(lattice_sizes, finite_size_scale(lattice_sizes, *args), 'r-',
             label='fit')
    plt.ylabel('critical temperature / arb. u.')
    plt.xlabel('Lattice size')
    save_plot('Finite size scaling')
    return args[0], sqrt(cov[0, 0])


# -------------------------------------------------------------------------

t_c = 2/log(1 + sqrt(2))
use_disk = False
breadth = 1
base_duration = 10
sizes = [16, 32]
# investigate_time_evolution()
# investigate_temperature_dependence(lattice_sizes=sizes, re_runs=4)

critical_temps = investigate_heat_capacity(lattice_sizes=sizes,
                                           take_last=10000)

# temp_inf = investigate_finite_size_scaling(critical_temps, sizes)

#  print(temp_inf)
# print((t_c - temp_inf[0])/ temp_inf[1], ' Standard errors away')
```

Here's the heat capacity,

[image: heat cap]

and [image: mean magnetisation]

Comment: Can you include the $c_v$ vs $T$ plots? And maybe a couple of energy time series for different lattice sizes and same $T$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are computing the specific heat by using the fluctuations of the energy per site rather than the total energy of the system. If you multiply the y axes of your plots by $N^2$ you should recover the expected behaviour.

By the way, you should not take into account "self energies" (that is, $e(i,i)$) in the `compute_energy` method.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this simulation before. I think you can solve your problem by first increasing the number averaging (Monte-Carlo method) and then increasing the size of the lattice. Since when you are doing in small sizes, the model feels the effect of size.
You can take a look at the following paper:
http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-5468/2009/07/P07030/pdf

Which talks about the effects of size.